# VS Code 1.3 Re-Enabling Markdown Preview

Tags: visual-studio-code

In version 1.3 of Visual Studio Code, looks like they removed the native markdown preview support and refactored it to be a VS Code extension.  The release notes mentions this, but doesn't recommend what plug-in(s) we should install to get this functionality back into the editor.

Does anyone know what plug-in we should be using to re-enable the Markdown Preview?

From the Release notes: https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/June_2016

> Extract Markdown into an extension
>   The Markdown language support has been refactored to be a regular VS Code extension. It uses the Markdown TextMate grammar for syntax highlighting source and renders the Markdown as HTML using the markdown-it library which implements the CommonMark Spec.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Markdown Preview is enabled in VS Code 1.3. What the release notes said is that feature has been moved to an preinstalled extension. You can check that in the sub-directory "extensions" of a VSCode installation. It contains a sub-folder "markdown". That's the markdown extension.
- Markdown Preview is moved into the context menu of a tab for some reasons. Check the issue on https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/8996

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I also got confused by the release notes. The most frustrating part was that I spent 20 minutes trying to find the extension... only to find out it was never removed.